# Bridge pattern example from "Designed Patterns Explained"

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns, bridge

I am studying an example of a Bridge Pattern from "Designed Patterns Explained".
The example I am looking at is Example 10.3 which can be found at

http://www.netobjectives.com/resources/books/design-patterns-explained/cpp-code-examples/chapter10#10-3

The specific confusion I have is with the Shape class and its derived classes.

```
#pragma once
#include "Drawing.h"

class Shape
{
public:
    Shape(Drawing *aDrawing);
    virtual void draw()= 0;

protected:
    Drawing *myDrawing;
    void drawLine( double, double, double, double);
    void drawCircle( double, double, double);

public:
    ~Shape(void);
};
```

In the Circle class we have

```
#pragma once
#include "Shape.h"

class Circle : public Shape
{
public:
    Circle(Drawing*, double, double, double);
    virtual void draw();
    virtual void drawCircle(double, double, double)=0;

public:
    ~Circle(void);
protected:
    double _x, _y, _r;
};
```

So the question I have is:
why can `drawCircle` be pure virtual in the inherited class given that the method is in fact implemented in the base class?

Comment: Well, why *shouldn't* it be able to be virtual?

Comment: you should reword your title to match your actual question; this has nothing to do with bridge pattern..

Comment: stijn - good point I perhaps should have included all the code. But the example is meant to be implementation of bridge pattern where the author has used the bridge pattern to decouple abstraction (shape class) from the implementation (Drawing class) where the call to drawCircle is providing the "bridge".

Answer (score 4):

Imagine you're building a module to draw shapes using different API's (windows GDI, some smartphone API, OpenGL, anything). Having a typical hierarchy `abstract Shape` `<---` `concrete Circle` and `abstract Shape` `<---` `concrete Rectangle` you would have to recompile and redeploy `Circle` and `Rectangle` each time you add a new framework and each time something changes in the existing framework. Such changes may even involve modifying the constructors of these classes so users of your module would have to also change their code.

Example: you have a working first version of your module, with the following interface for `Circle`:

```
class Circle : public Shape
{
  public:
    Circle(int x, int y, int radius);

    void draw(...);
};
```

Then, it happens that optimization reasons for one of the platforms force you to know the `DPI` resolution of the current platform in advance (before actually drawing the circle). So, you would have to change the constructor:

```
class Circle : public Shape
{
  public:
    Circle(int x, int y, int radius, int dpi);

    void draw(...);
};
```

and clients of your code would have to recompile their applications. There would be of course some hacks possible to avoid this (like introducing `CircleWithDpi`), but they would lead to a highly coupled and hard to maintain code. If you use the bridge pattern you can have your clear design left intact and still express your domain (in general, concept of a "circle" shouldn't know anything about a thing called "dpi resolution").

So having:

```
class Circle : public Shape
{
  public:
    Circle(int x, int y, int radius);

    virtual void draw(...) = 0;
};
```

and

```
class CircleImpl : public Circle
{
  public:
    CircleImpl(int x, int y, int radius, int dpi);
    //perform some calculations before drawing for optimization

    void draw(...);
    //draw using appropriate API
};
```

and

```
class ShapeFactory
{
  public:
    virtual Circle* CreateCircle(int x, int y, int radius) = 0;
};
```

Of course you would have many `CircleImpl`s - each for different platform your module supports (so, `CircleImplGDI`, `CircleImplTk`, `CircleImplOpenGL` etc.).

In the implementation of the `ShapeFactory` you'd create a particular `CircleImpl` appropriately and the client of your module doesn't have to know anything about it. This example is the simplified version of the one you've given link to. Note that now, when one of possible `CircleImpl`s is used as `Circle` no abstract classes are being instantiated, so this should also clear out your issue about abstract derived class.

The main idea behind this pattern is to have two levels of abstraction: `Shape` is an abstract geometrical concept, `Circle` and `Rectangle` are more concrete than the `Shape` but in the context of many technical possibilities for drawing them they are still quite abstract. Concrete representations of particular shapes exist when you know the context: for example - drawing on a raster or using vector graphics.

Another level of abstraction gives you possibility to defer some more decisions about your code - at first we defer the decision about what shapes we have. Then, having `Circle` and `Rectangle` we defer the decision about how to draw them. And deferred decisions give us decoupled, flexible code (as demonstrated with the "added DPI" example).

Answer (score 1):

Pure virtual methods are allowed in any class, as long as you don't try to create an instance of that class.

Comment: Yes, my issue with this example is not that the derived class is pure virtual but that the implementation is defined in the base class. Another issue is that both the base and derived classes are both abstract so clearly there is an error...

Comment: @emza0114 You should update your question with this information. And why would it be an error to have both parent and child classes being abstract?

Comment: well as you said what can I create an instance of?

Comment: @emza0114 The code example you link to is missing a lot of code. It compiles because it never creates the actual instances.